# Something like Snoop for Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I have used the application snoop for debugging WPF applications.

http://blois.us/Snoop/

It helps to break down the XAML at runtime and understand the GUI hierarchy, and find binding errors etc.

Is there anything like that for Silverlight?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [SilverlightSpy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy/). (doesn't look like it's free, though)

Comment: Nice one. At least there is a 21 day trial of the full product and a "free mode" which has limited functionality.